# Multi DNS provider setup

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, dns-hosting, cloudflare

If I setup DNS records for a zone to sync between AWS Route53 and Cloudflare, do I set the nameservers at my registar to both Cloudflare nameservers (brad.ns.cloudflare.com, beth.ns.cloudflare.com) and AWS route53 nameservers (ns-1232.awsdns-26.org, ...)? Or, do I setup one DNS provider as primary, and in case of an outage manually update the name servers to the backup DNS provider? Isn't there a very long delay (24 hours+) when updating nameservers for a zone?

Answer (score 2):

Both Cloudflare and AWS provides the redundancy within the service by giving you authoritative name servers that are on independent networks. It's not likely that whole Cloudflare or AWS would be down. Frankly, your setup seems like a overkill.

If you do use both for additional redundancy, you certainly list both name servers at the registrar. Changing authoritative name servers would always take longer than any possible outage.